# Erro HTTPS SSLv3 Indy Delphi 7

Tags: http, delphi-7, openssl, http-post, indy-10

Estou tentando fazer conexão via HTTPS utilizando SSLv3(necessário para consumir um serviço específico), mas quando eu tento realizar o post, obtenho o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro no SSL]

A princípio, creio que seja um problema na configuração dos componentes.
Já dei uma pesquisada mas não consegui resolver meu problema.
Segue o código da configuração dos componentes e envio:

```
var
   _idhttp : TIdHttp;
   _idSSL : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
   _retorno : String;
begin

   _idSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(nil);
   with _idSSL do
   begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
      SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
   end;

   _idhttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  with _idhttp do
  begin
     IOHandler := _idSSL;
     AllowCookies := true;
     ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := true;
     ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
     request.ContentLength := -1;
     request.ContentRangeEnd := 0;
     request.ContentRangeStart := 0;
     Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
     request.BasicAuthentication := false;
     request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
     HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
     HandleRedirects := true;
  end;

  retorno := _idhttp.Post(URL,xmlIn);

end;
```

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda. Abraços!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa, consegui resolver meu problema!
Antes de mais nada, atualizei a versão do Indy(Delphi 7) para a versão mais recente.

E também tive que atualizar e colocar na pasta da aplicação as DLL's do SSL, que baixei no seguinte link(sim, tem captcha): http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

A configuração dos componentes foi a seguinte:

```
var
   retorno : String;//variável que recebe o retorno da requisição
   param : TStringStream;//é onde eu coloco as informações que vão ser enviadas via POST



try
  _idSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil); //SSL
  _idhttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  with _idhttp do
  begin
     IOHandler := _idSSL;
     ReadTimeout := 0;
     AllowCookies := true;
     ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := true;
     ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
     request.ContentLength := -1;
     request.ContentRangeEnd := 0;
     request.ContentRangeStart := 0;
     Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
     request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
     request.CharSet := 'utf-8';
     request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
  end;
  param := TStringStream.Create(xmlIn.Text);//xmlIn é um objeto da classe TStringList que contém os valores a serem enviados
  retorno := _idhttp.Post(URL,param);
  result := retorno;
except
  on e: exception do
  begin
     raise Exception.Create('Erro ao enviar requisição: ' + #13 + e.Message);
     result := '';
  end;
end;
```

Qualquer dúvida, deixem um comentário. Ficarei feliz em poder ajudar.

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços!